# Query for counting unread posts

Tags: mysql

I'm building a system where I need to display unread counters for blog posts.

All blog posts have a category and the website is setup that it the user clicks on a category, and it then loads all the posts of that category.

The database structure is as following:

`wp_posts`
`wp_posts_reads`
`wp_users`

A new `wp_posts_read` entry is made when reading a post, it has the following columns:

- `post_id`
- `user_id`
- `date`

I need the following query:

- Get the unread count within a specific post category, for a specific user

This is what I tried, but it's not returning the unread count correctly and throwing an error

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) unread_count, posts.*, posts_reads.*
FROM wp_posts posts
  INNER JOIN wp_posts_read posts_read
    ON posts.id = posts_read.post_id
WHERE posts_read.user_id = 4
  AND posts.category IS 'ratings'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS unread_count
FROM wp_posts posts
WHERE posts.category = 'ratings'
AND posts.id NOT IN (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_posts_reads
    WHERE user_id = 4
)
```

If it doesnt work, please send us the error the query is throwing.

Comment: So in SQL it's possible to `WHERE posts_read ...` while that table is not joined?

Comment: Errr, no, i made a mistake, i'm going to correct it.